# How to transfer a filter to a query (TypeORM)

Tags: sql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I want to get rid of the filter and put it in the request body. I tried using where, how can I do it?

Questionnaire entity like:

```
@OneToMany(() => LikeEntity, (like) => like.questionnaire)
    @JoinTable()
    likes: LikeEntity[];

    @OneToMany(() => DislikeEntity, (dislike) => dislike.questionnaire)
    @JoinTable()
    dislikes: DislikeEntity[];
```

Code:

```
const questionnaires = await this.questionnairesRepository.find({
                relations: ['likes', 'dislikes'],
                where: [
                    {
                        userId: Not(questionnaire.userId),
                        likes: {
                            id: 12,
                        },
                    },
                ],
                order: {
                    id: 'ASC',
                },
            });

            if (!questionnaires)
                throw new HttpException('Questionnaires not found', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

            return questionnaires
                .filter((questionnaire) => {
                    return (
                        !questionnaire.likes.find((like) => like.ownerUserId == userId) &&
                        !questionnaire.dislikes.find((like) => like.ownerUserId == userId)
                    );
                })
                .slice(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `createQueryBuilder`, you can left join or inner join table easier

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.